Argument type match with rest parameter in type alias and its implementation
Newbie to TypeScript, and I'm confused about the folowing snippet:
type Fn = (...args: number[]) => void

const fn1: Fn = (x) => console.log(x);
const fn2: Fn = (x1, x2) => console.log(x1, x2);

fn1(2);
fn2(2, 4);

In my understanding, ...args is a rest parameter where indefinite number of arguments is allowed and you can access args as array, but its implementations fn1 and fn2 doesn't implement with rest parameter or access it as array. fn1 only accept 1 argument, and fn2accept 2 arguments only.
Is this a specific feature of rest parameter in type keyword? If so, where can I find the specfication?
Please feel free to tell me if there's anything unclear to you.
I expected the implementaion of Fn should be something like
const fn: Fn = (...x: number[]) => console.log(x);


https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

So, I guess, what it basically means is the rest parameter ...args: number[] is abstract type for 0 or more number arguments, and fn1 and fn2 are allowed as subsets of the abstract type. Is that correct?

Both of your implementations can accept an arbitrary number of number arguments. They just ignore most of them.

You can call fn1 and fn2 with as many or as few inputs as you like, like fn1(1,2,3,4,5).  Passing in more than the implementation expects is fine and is the point of the link in the first comment. Passing in fewer than the implementation expects is unsafe (e.g., you could write console.log(x.toFixed(1)) in there and then have problems when x is undefined, but TS misses this), but it's a known unsafeness, see ms/TS#46063. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Ok, so at least there was something I was misunderstanding about the rest parameter.
Let's consider the simple example of a fucntion with rest parameter.
const sum = (...args: number[]) : number => {
    let result = 0;
    for(const num of args) { 
        result += num;
    }
    return result;
};

When you call this function, you can pass an arbitary number of arguments, like sum(1), sum(1, 2), sum(1, 2, 3), ..., but you cannot pass an array like sum([1, 2, 3,]) (you will get an syntax error Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.).
I guess this answers my question. Same applies to the implementaion of Fn. The rest parameter doesn't mean it accepts the arguments of array, but it can accept "an unbounded number of (rest) arguments". You can access it as array when you recieve arguments with rest parameter, but we don't use rest parameters in both fn1 and fn2.

The question as asked doesn't make it look like you thought you could call a Fn with a single array argument (e.g., f([1, 2, 3])), but this answer talks almost exclusively about that. Could you edit the question to ask e.g., "why doesn't fn1([2]) work", or at least mention the possibility of calling the function with an array in there? Otherwise it doesn't quite seem like the question and answer go together (the answer might clear up a confusion you had, but that confusion is not mentioned in the question).
